# Limpar corpo da tabela antes de de popular novamente com Jquery e Ajax

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
$("#numeroRequisicao").change(function() {
    var numeroRequisicao = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../controller/ajax.selectItemRequisicaoPesquisar.php?numeroRequisicao="+numeroRequisicao,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(res) {
            for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++)
            {
                $("#tab_logic").append('<tr class="text-center"><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+res[i].nome_GAThemocomponente+'</td><td>'+res[i].qtd_GATitemRequisicao+'</td><td>'+res[i].frequencia_GATitemRequisicao+'</td><td>'+res[i].cirurgia_GATitemRequisicao+'</td></tr>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

E a seguinte tabela em HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="tab_logic">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">Indice</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 25%;">Hemocomponente</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%;">Quantidade</th>
            <th class="text-center">Frequência (Aviso)</th>
            <th class="text-center">Cirurgia (Aviso)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Quando o usuario clicar no botão `btnPesquisar`, a função Ajax vai ser disparada, pega os itens e preenche a tabela, está funcionando corretamente isso, o problema é o seguinte:

Se o usuário escolher a requisição de código 1 e clicar no botão `btnPesquisar`, vai preencher a tabela com os itens da requisição de código 1, porém se o usuario não der refresh na pagina e quiser ver a requisição de código 2, os itens da requisição de código 2 serão adicionados na tabela sem ela ser limpa, ficando assim, os itens da requisição anteriormente vista junto com os da requisição vista no momento.

Como eu poderia fazer pra limpar a tabela antes de preencher com os novos dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gera uma string com tudo e assim já podes apagar tudo de uma vez:

```js
success: function(res) {
    var html = res.reduce(function(string, obj, i) {
      return string + '<tr class="text-center"><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + obj.nome_GAThemocomponente + '</td><td>' + obj.qtd_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td>' + obj.frequencia_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td>' + obj.cirurgia_GATitemRequisicao + '</td></tr>'
    }, '');
    $("#tab_logic tbody").html(html);
}
```

Comment: mas assim a tabela vai perder o `thead` também?, o seletor seria `$("#tab_logic tbody").html(html)`

Comment: @fernandoandrade caso haja `thead` e `tbody` podes usar um selector para ter isso em conta assim: `$("#tab_logic tbody").html(html);`

Comment: foi isso que eu quis dizer @sergio, no exemplo da pergunta tem `thead` e `tbody`aí do jeito na resposta vai remover tudo da tabela.

Comment: @fernandoandrade ah, não tinha reparado no HTML. Obrigado, corrigi!

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta @Sergio, mas não está funcionando corretamente. Eu copiei o código escrito por você e encaixei no meu e não está preenchendo a tabela. Antes do `var html...`, eu coloquei um `alert(res)` pra ver se o resultado estava vindo, e está vindo corretamente, não está montando a tabela no caso. O que você acha que poderia ser? Obrigado!

Comment: @GabrielQ. testa de novo, corrigi um erro que tinha deixado ao adaptar do teu código.

Comment: Agora funcionou perfeitamente @Sergio. Muito obrigado mesmo! Meus conhecimentos são bem poucos em JS/Jquery e sua resposta foi certeira e de grande ajuda. Obrigado!